# "Fall", "fell", "felled"

Tags: word-usage, simple-past, verb-forms, causative-verbs

How is the causative form of *fall* used in English?
In the present tense, often enough,

> A tree *falls* in the woods, but a logger *falls* trees as well.

but in the past tense,

> A *tree* fell in the woods, but the logger *felled* a tree.

However, if it's not a tree, or if it's not a person's normal course of work to fall trees, then *fell* is used to mean "cause [some structure, regime, etc.] to fall."

> Someone will *fell* that evil dynasty one day.

As far as I know "falled" is not a word, and "fell" is not a past-tense form in the causative sense.

Comment: You need to post a dictionary reference licensing the transitive usage of _fall_ you inply exists.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

Your only error is that the causative form is *fell* in the present tense: *A logger fells trees today*. Otherwise you've got it right.

> causative: **fell, felled, has/be felled**, as opposed to
>   intransitive: **fall, fell, has fallen**

However, *felling* a dynasty or regime, or anything except a man, animal, or tree, is pretty rare today; *OED 1* was already marking it as obsolete in 1895. *Topple* (in the transitive use) is more common.

**EDIT -- taking a healthy bite of my words.**
On review I find that *falling a tree* is in fact still in use. The usage appears, on a quick Google scan, to be confined to the western US, and to non-formal usage; but it's something more than rare.

As for declension: Google reports 5 (non-duplicate) instances of *falled a tree*, 17 of *he fell a tree*, 13 of *has fallen a tree*, and none of *has falled a tree*. So the regular strong form seems to prevail.

Comment: I found a photo on the net of a use of "fall" meaning "cause a tree to fall": http://www.justinshull.net/2009/07/24/branches-break-off-of-cell-tower-tree/ (different justin--I am not affiliated).  Are you saying this is a grammatical error?

Comment: @justin--  Not quite. I'm saying it's a lexical error.

Comment: Surely the sign "SEED TREE / DO NOT FALL" is not to be interpreted as ordering the tree not to fall?

Comment: @justin--  See my edit. I'd stick with *fell* for transitive in formal use, but I can't fault DoI for employing the dialect of the folks they're addressing. Thanks!--I've learned something.

Comment: Okay, now, "falled a tree" and "he fell a tree" are baby-talk.

Comment: Interesting.  (The part in the edit).  I just googled "he fell a tree".  I got 27 non-duplicate hits, but many were things like "... nor should he fell a tree ..." and "... never did he fell a tree ...".  There was also "... he fell.  A tree caught him."  I think only 11 of them were a past tense of a transitive "fall".  Call me an evil prescriptivist, but I would consider any usage with only 11 hits across all of google's data to be an error.

Comment: @DavidWallace   As I said, I counted 17, eliminating those you cite. *fall* v.tr. is pretty rare anyway; what I was looking for is strong vs weak declension.

Answer (score 3):

These are two completely different verbs.  There's

> fall | fell | fallen

which is intransitive.  Also, there's

> fell | felled | felled

which is transitive.

So a tree can fall.  A tree fell.  Ten trees have fallen today.

John can fell a tree.  John felled a tree.  John has felled ten trees today.

Your sentence fragment "a logger falls trees" is incorrect, as far as I know.

Comment: Many people say it's incorrect, but it is very common usage at least in the Pacific NW.  I remember when I was a small child and a logger came to fall a tree in our backyard.  The next day, I said "He fell that tree."  I was corrected, "No, he *felled* that tree."  "Why didn't he say he was going to *fell* it, then?"  "No, no, no. Loggers *fall* trees."  "Well, then he *falled* it."  "No. He *felled* the tree."  That's just the way it is, and it comes across as somewhat archaic or foreign when someone says that "a logger fells trees."

Comment: Right.  Which is exactly why I said "as far as I know".  I have never heard this usage, but I have no reason to disbelieve you.  It seems that no matter what we say about English, there'll be some dialect somewhere where it doesn't apply.

Comment: Only loggers *fall* trees, though.  Storms *fell* trees.

Comment: @justin-- You're in trouble with 'The storm and the logger V-ed the tree between them', then.